# Centralizer of a finitely generated subgroup, index

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a group and $A,B \leq G$. Suppose that the order of $\left[ A,B\right ]$ is $n$ and that 
$A$ is $m$-generated by $a_1,\dots,a_m$. Show that the centralizer in $B$ of $A$ has index $\leq n^m$ in $B$.
I tried to consider
\begin{align*}
\lvert B:C_B(A) \rvert \,=\, & \lvert B: \cap_i C_B(a_i) \rvert \,\leq\, \prod_{i=1}^m 
\lvert B: C_B(a_i) \rvert \\ \,=\, & \prod_{i=1}^m \lvert \operatorname{cl}(a_i) \rvert 
\,\leq\, \lvert \left[ A,B \right] \rvert^m
\end{align*}
because $a_i^b = a_i \left[  a_i, b\right]$, so $|\operatorname{cl}(a_i)| \leq 
\lvert a_i \left[ A,B \right] \rvert = \lvert \left[ A,B \right] \rvert.$
Is it correct?

Comment: Yes it's correct!